# Google Maps marker as a link

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using Google Maps for my website and I wander how can I use the **Markers** as links? I mean when I click a marker to open a particular link.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's actually very easy to do. Simply attach an event handler to your marker, and then launch the link by setting `window.location.href` to your URL. Check out the following examples, which I think should be self explanatory:

Using the [v3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Marker as a Link</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 2,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.55, -25.75),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.getCenter(),
      url: 'http://www.google.com/',
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.location.href = marker.url;
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using the [V2 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps Marker as a Link</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body onunload="GUnload()"> 
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      var centerPoint = new GLatLng(35.55, -25.75);
      map.setCenter(centerPoint, 2);

      var marker = new GMarker(map.getCenter());
      marker.url = 'http://www.google.com/';
      map.addOverlay(marker);

      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {     
        window.location.href = marker.url;
      });
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

The above examples will add a marker somewhere in the atlantic ocean. When you click on it, you'll be forwarded to a popular search engine.

Comment: Hey +1 added duly, but what if you want to open this link in new window, I tried window.open= marker.url; and then an attribute like 
url: "http://www.google.com",
target: "_blank" to the marker object but to no avail,

Answer (score 3):

To get this to open in a new tab add the following right after the "window.location.href = marker.url;":

```
window.open(this.url, '_blank');
```

So you would have:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.location.href = marker.url;
      window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    });
```