# How to link different URLs to multiple map markers for API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Checked these out here:

[Google Maps API V3 multiple markers with links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088595/google-maps-api-v3-multiple-markers-with-links)

[Google Maps marker as a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056213/google-maps-marker-as-a-link)

but they didn't help. I'm not programming savvy and total n00b.  I'm simply trying to add some marker animations to my webpage.  I'd like to be able to click on an individual marker once it settles and be redirected to that associated marker url.

Update: thank you so much for following up on this. However I get a blank screen when I try to run the html page.  I updated my code below. I also removed the z index and put all your code updates between the  tags inside the  tag) Finally, I removed the intialize(); call function and instead used the . Running the code should theoretically drop 3 markers onto the map with the designated urls given the neighborhoods.length = 3. However the page still remains blank after refreshing.

So something is blocking the browser from loading the map onto the page. Does the map-canvas need to be adjusted in the ? My updated code is in next post below: –

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker animations with <code>setTimeout()</code></title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

      </head>

 <body onload="initialize()";>

<script>  

<div id="panel" style="margin-left: -52px">

<button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Drop Markers</button>
     </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

var sacramento = new google.maps.LatLng(38.576725, -121.493715);

var iterator = 0;  // I added back this initialized variable which        //wasn't in your adjusted code shown here

var neighborhoods = [
new google.maps.LatLng(38.576725, -121.493715),
new google.maps.LatLng(35.011263, -115.473376),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.941820, -118.408466)];

var markers = [];
var map;
var mapUrl = [
    'http://www.google.com',
    'http://www.youtube.com',
    'http://maps.google.com'];

function initialize() {
   {......etc. }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code. Syntax, etc. I have removed a few things from your code to make it easier to understand (setTimeout, toggleBounce, etc.). And I added the call to `drop()` function in the `initialize()` function. I also replaced the `window.location.href` by a display of the URL in a DIV. Check the fiddle link at the bottom.

```
var sacramento = new google.maps.LatLng(38.576725, -121.493715);

var neighborhoods = [
new google.maps.LatLng(38.576725, -121.493715),
new google.maps.LatLng(35.011263, -115.473376),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.941820, -118.408466)];

var markers = [];
var map;
var mapUrl = [
    'http://www.google.com',
    'http://www.youtube.com',
    'http://maps.google.com'];

function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: sacramento
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    drop();
}

function drop() {
    for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
        addMarker(i);
    }
}

function addMarker(iterator) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: neighborhoods[iterator],
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        url: mapUrl[iterator],
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        document.getElementById('goToLocation').innerHTML = 'Will send you to ' + this.url;
    });

    markers.push(marker);
}

initialize();
```

This should help you to get started.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/JMpHW/)</kbd>

Comment: thank you so much for following up on this. However I get a blank screen when I try to run the html page.  I updated my code below. I also removed the z index and put all your code updates between the <script> tags inside the <body> tag) Finally, I removed the intialize(); call function and instead used the <body onload="initialize()";>. Running the code should theoretically drop 3 markers onto the map with the designated urls given the neighborhoods.length = 3. However the page still remains blank after refreshing.

Comment: So something is blocking the browser from loading the map onto the page.  Does the map-canvas need to be adjusted in the <style>?  My updated code is in next post below:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker animations with <code>setTimeout()</code></title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"
     type="text/javascript"></script>  
      </head>
 con't